# Vue JS | Mouse cursor magnet, эффект магнитизма при наведении

Tags: vue.js, анимация, cursor, gsap

Не получается создать эффект примагничивания, пытался завести эффект от сюда, не венчалось успехом

[Ссылка на рабочий результат.](https://codepen.io/phucbm/pen/RmbGOQ) |
[Ссылка на второй рабочий результат.](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomCursors/index3.html)

**[Ссылка на мой результат.](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-solomon-dl574)** (код на vue, поэтому выложил на sanbox)

При наведении эффект увеличения срабатывает, но эффект примагничивания нет.

```
кода нет, все в песочнице
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что-то такое получилось:

```js
let actual = [0, 0, 0], target = [0, 0, 0], xy = [0,0];
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];
addEventListener('mousemove', requestCursorPosition);
addEventListener('scroll', requestCursorPosition);
requestAnimationFrame(moveCursor);

function requestCursorPosition(e) {
    let X = xy[0] = (e.x || xy[0]);
    let Y = xy[1] = (e.y || xy[1]);
    let snap = elements.map(el => {
        let r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        let x = r.x + r.width/2 - X;
        let y = r.y + r.height/2 - Y;
        return [x, y, x*x + y*y];
    }).find(el => el[2] < 900);
    
    target[0] = (snap ? snap[0] : 0) + X + window.pageXOffset;
    target[1] = (snap ? snap[1] : 0) + Y + window.pageYOffset;
    target[2] = snap ? 15 : 5;
}

function moveCursor() {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
        actual[i] += (target[i] - actual[i])/5;
    
    document.body.style.background = 
        `radial-gradient(
            circle at ${actual[0]}px ${actual[1]}px, 
            #0000, 
            #0000 ${actual[2]}px, 
            #0007 ${actual[2]+1}px,
            #0007 ${actual[2]+2}px,
            #0000 ${actual[2]+3}px)`;
            
    requestAnimationFrame(moveCursor);
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href=#>test 1</a>
<a href=# style="position:absolute;bottom:20px">test 2</a>
<a href=#>test 3</a>
<a href=# style="float:right">test 4</a>
```

Comment: понятно где "примагничивание" в коде ? :)

Comment: вполне понятно, минимум кода и все понятно, сейчас буду интегрировать данный экземпляр во vue, спасибо большое!

Comment: Не подскажите как сделать расстояние по которому будет отмагничиваться курсор? `const h = Math.sqrt(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y);` в частности с этой строкой, по идее это должна была быть проверка, если `h < 100`, то будет примагничен, а если больше, то отлипать будет.

Comment: @MoloF у меня в коде это 900 (30*30), я проверяю квадрат расстояния, чтобы не вычислять корень

Comment: Колдунство. ‎ +1

Comment: @yar85 готовлю ответ где в 2 раза меньше кода =)

Answer (score 3):

Вот вариант с элементом, а не бэкграундом в качестве курсора

```js
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let snap = elements.map(el => {
        let r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        let x = r.x + r.width/2 - e.x;
        let y = r.y + r.height/2 - e.y;
        return [x, y, x*x + y*y]; 
    }).find(el => el[2] < 900);
    cursor.style.left = (snap?snap[0]*0.7-11:0) + e.x + window.pageXOffset - 7 + 'px';
    cursor.style.top =  (snap?snap[1]*0.7-11:0) + e.y + window.pageYOffset - 7 + 'px';
    cursor.style.height = cursor.style.width = (snap ? 36 : 14) + 'px';
    cursor.style.border = (snap ? 2 : 1.1) + 'px solid #0005';
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href=#>test 1</a>
<a href=#>test 2</a>
<a href=#>test 3</a>
<a href=# style="float:right;display:inline-block;margin:100px">test 4</a>
<div id=cursor></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но саму суть магнита я сделал, жаль не могу сделать эффект натяжения, когда примагничен, но не полностью, а внутри элемента продолжает двигаться но с небольшой натяжкой когда отводишь от элемента, а так все круто и полностью то что нужно

Comment: @MoloF я плохо понял в чем муть проблемы

Comment: https://codepen.io/phucbm/pen/RmbGOQ здесь элемент не намертво магнитится, а дает двигать сам курсор, но при этом, при оттягивании, он имеет эффект натяжения

Comment: @MoloF сейчас попробуем

Comment: @MoloF вроде что-то получилось

Comment: У меня воспроизводимый пример как-то рывками работает, мб где-то допущена ошибка?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103560/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-molof).